# Retrive value of a url field using client object model

Tags: client-object-model, sharepoint-addin

I want to get the value of a URL field type using client object model. As I am working with share point app so can't use the server object model. Can anyone please hepl me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
SP.ListItem.get_item('urlfieldname').get_url()
```

For more details.

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2011/07/06/how-to-get-various-item-fields-using-client-object-model-ecmascript-sharepoint-2010/

http://mybadcode.blogspot.in/2013/04/get-fields-using-javascript-client.html